# When is `React.createClass({})()` called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm digging through the `React.js` source and this is what I'm currently trying to understand.

```
var ReactClass = {
    /*
    * @param {object} spec Class specification (which must define `render`).
    * @return {function} Component constructor function.
    * @public
    */
    createClass: function(spec) {
        var Constructor = function(props, context) {
            // ...
            this.props = props;
            this.context = context;
            this.state = null;

            // ReactClasses doesn't have constructors. Instead, they use the
            // getInitialState and componentWillMount methods for initialization.
            var initialState = this.getInitialState ? this.getInitialState() : null;
            // ...
            this.state = initialState;
        };

        Constructor.prototype = new ReactClassComponent();
        Constructor.prototype.constructor = Constructor;
        // ...
        mixSpecIntoComponent(Constructor, spec);
        // ...
        return Constructor; // <--- Who calls this?
    },
    // ...
};
```

When calling `React.createClass({})` you get the `Constructor` function that takes two parameters `props, context`.

Where is this function/method called, I.e. who does the actual `React.createClass({})(someProps, someContext)`?

Comment: Well, whenever *you* instantiate a `new MyReactClass` it is called

Comment: @Bergi outside of `var inst = new Component(publicProps, publicContext);` I just can't find it anywhere in the source...

Comment: In which source are you looking? I'd expect these user-customised classes to be called from application code, not from library code.

Comment: https://fb.me/react-0.13.3.js the source file. You never call your `ReactClass` instances, you just append them to the `React` tree. That's why I'm searching...

Comment: How are you defining your components if not with `React.createClass`? Your example, `var inst = new Component(publicProps, publicContext);`, that's it. That's where it's being called. What are you expecting to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not straightforward, you're right.

The short answer is that `Constructor` is called by `React.render`.

See here for the actual instantiation block: https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/4c3e9650ba6c9ea90956a08542d9fa9b5d72ee88/src/renderers/shared/reconciler/instantiateReactComponent.js#L75

The basic path is this:

- You create a `ReactClass`, which has a return value of `Constructor`.
- When you create a factory (either directly with `React.createFactory` or abstractly via JSX), your class gets bound to `React.createElement` as `type`, with the bound function getting returned (see [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/v0.13.3/src/classic/element/ReactElement.js#L203)).
- This bound function is what is actually getting called when you call your class with (or without) props.
- When this is passed to `render` as `node`, the `render` method (linked above) sets an `element` variable to the `node` argument and then instantiates it directly or passes it to other libs to instantiate.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this more than once! Great answer.